# Pairwise division or multiplication of each row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am not sure if my title is appropriate. I have a matrix of a column and 500 rows. I want to divide (of multiply) the values of each row with other values. The result matrix should also have one column.

For example
Input matrix:

A | 5

B | 1

C | 2

D | 4

Result matrix should go like this:

A/B | 5

A/C | 2.5

A/D | 1.25

B/A | 0.2

B/C | 0.5

B/D | 0.25

C/A .............

How can I do it in R with dplyr or base function?

Comment: `help("outer")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `outer` (or its infix operator `%o%`) for this:

Suppose your input matrix is:

```
x <- as.matrix(c(A=5, B=1, C=2, D=4))
```

Then your output is:

```
y <- as.matrix((1/x) %o% x)
```

The slightly tricky bit is the rownames, but `outer` can do this as well (maybe there's a better way)

```
rownames(y) <- outer(rownames(x), rownames(x), \(x,y) paste(y,"/",x)) |> as.vector()

> y
      [,1]
A / A 1.00
A / B 5.00
A / C 2.50
A / D 1.25
B / A 0.20
B / B 1.00
B / C 0.50
B / D 0.25
C / A 0.40
C / B 2.00
C / C 1.00
C / D 0.50
D / A 0.80
D / B 4.00
D / C 2.00
D / D 1.00
```

If you want to remove the "A / A" etc...

```
> y[!diag(length(x)),] |> as.matrix()
      [,1]
A / B 5.00
A / C 2.50
A / D 1.25
B / A 0.20
B / C 0.50
B / D 0.25
C / A 0.40
C / B 2.00
C / D 0.50
D / A 0.80
D / B 4.00
D / C 2.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tidy solution, though it is perhaps a bit more cumbersome than other solutions.  First you make the base data frame that just has single letters and corresponding numbers.

```r
library(dplyr)  
library(tidyr)
lets <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
vals <- c(5,1,2,4)
base_dat <- data.frame(letter = lets, 
                       value = vals)
```

Next, you use the `crossing()` function from the `tidyr` package to make all combinations of the letters and themselves.  Then, set the names of the data frame to be `"letters1"` and `"letters2"`. Then you do two left-joins, one to get the numbers for the first set of letters and then another to get the numbers for the second set of letters.  Finally, `transmute()` will allow you to generate the names from both sets of letters and the values from both sets of numbers.

```r
crossing(lets, lets)  %>% 
  setNames(c("letter1", "letter2")) %>% 
  left_join(base_dat %>% rename(letter1=letter, value1 = value)) %>% 
  left_join(base_dat %>% rename(letter2=letter, value2 = value)) %>% 
  transmute(name = paste(letter1, letter2, sep="/"), 
            value = value1/value2)
#> Joining, by = "letter1"
#> Joining, by = "letter2"
#> # A tibble: 16 × 2
#>    name  value
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A/A    1   
#>  2 A/B    5   
#>  3 A/C    2.5 
#>  4 A/D    1.25
#>  5 B/A    0.2 
#>  6 B/B    1   
#>  7 B/C    0.5 
#>  8 B/D    0.25
#>  9 C/A    0.4 
#> 10 C/B    2   
#> 11 C/C    1   
#> 12 C/D    0.5 
#> 13 D/A    0.8 
#> 14 D/B    4   
#> 15 D/C    2   
#> 16 D/D    1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c(5,1,2,4)
n <- length(x)
rep(x, each = n - 1)/x[sequence(rep(n, n - 1L), 1:n) %% n + 1L]
#>  [1] 5.00 2.50 1.25 0.20 0.50 0.25 0.40 2.00 0.50 0.80 4.00 2.00
```

Or with named vectors

```
x <- setNames(c(5,1,2,4), LETTERS[1:4])
nm <- names(x)
n <- length(x)
i <- (sequence(rep(n, n - 1L), 1:n) %% n + 1L)
setNames(
  rep(x, each = n - 1)/x[i],
  paste(rep(nm, each = n - 1), nm[i], sep = "/")
)
#>  A/B  A/C  A/D  B/A  B/C  B/D  C/A  C/B  C/D  D/A  D/B  D/C 
#> 5.00 2.50 1.25 0.20 0.50 0.25 0.40 2.00 0.50 0.80 4.00 2.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `bind_cols` and `expand_grid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(df$c1, df$c1) %>% 
  rename_with(function(x) c("a", "b")) %>% 
  filter(a!=b) %>% 
  summarize(a = paste0(a,"/",b)) %>% 
  bind_cols(., expand_grid(df$c2, df$c2) %>% 
    rename_with(function(x) c("a", "b")) %>% 
    filter(a!=b) %>% 
    summarize(a/b))
# A tibble: 12 × 2
   a     `a/b`
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A/B    5   
 2 A/C    2.5 
 3 A/D    1.25
 4 B/A    0.2 
 5 B/C    0.5 
 6 B/D    0.25
 7 C/A    0.4 
 8 C/B    2   
 9 C/D    0.5 
10 D/A    0.8 
11 D/B    4   
12 D/C    2
```

With **dplyr** >= 1.1.0 use `reframe` instead of `summarize`

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(c1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), c2 = c(5L, 1L, 2L, 
4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```